# What did the sages of blessed memory say about this phrase "sons of the priests"?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, kohen-priest, family-members, book-of-chronicles, ezra-nechemya

> 1 Chronicles 9:30 And some of the sons of the priests were compounders
> of the mixture for the spices.
> https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16529/showrashi/true
>
> Ezra 10:18 And it was found of the sons of the priests who brought in
> foreign women, of the sons of Jeshua, the son of Jozadak, and his
> brothers: Maaseiah, Eliezer, Jarib, and Gedaliah.
> https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16507/showrashi/true

In regards to the phrase "sons of the priests" (in either of the above passages), were these literal "sons of the priests"? If so, the phrase could have easily been shortened to "the priests" instead of "the sons of the priests", since the literal sons of the priests are themselves priests.

What did the sages of blessed memory say about this phrase "sons of the priests"?

Comment: Also Nechemiah 12:35. Possibly Ezra 2:61 as well (comp. Nechemiah 7:63).

Comment: I don't think b'nei means sons here. It probably means "members of". E.g. בני בליעל for wicked people.

Comment: @N.T. That opens up a new question: what does "members of the priests" mean, as opposed to literal/figurative "sons of the priests"?

Comment: Perhaps it's comparable to the term "sons of the prophets" (בני הנביאים) which refers to students of prophets; people who were studying how to become prophets.

Comment: @ninamag "since the literal sons of the priests are themselves priests." Not always. The sons of priests born of a forbidden union are halalim (disqualified) and not fit to serve as priests. Accordingly, the sons of priests are not always priests, but merely the "sons of priests"

Comment: @Deuteronomy I understand what you are saying, but as according to the first passage quoted, "1 Chronicles 9:30 And some of the sons of the priests were compounders of the mixture for the spices." - It has been said that the "compounders of the mixture for the spices" can only be qualified priests. Therefore your comment, based on this point is moot; your point would have been (or is) relevant, I suppose, for the next quoted passage: "Ezra 10:18 And it was found of the sons of the priests who brought in foreign women ...."

Comment: @ninamag that's besides the point. What I am conveying is that your line "since the literal sons of the priests are themselves priests" as stated unequivocally and without qualification is false. There are times when the priesthood is passed on and there are times that it is not.

Comment: @ninamag as for your primary question: בני הכהנים simply seems to follow the convention used for other tribal and subtribal units. Ancestral clans named according to their progenitors. The chapter in Chronicles you cite has the term בני used thirteen times, and in the chapter in Ezra seventeen times. It is a literary convention, why assume anything more significant, particularly in light of the fact that the priesthood does **not** in fact always pass on?

Comment: @Deuteronomy your point then is that the term "sons" should or should not be taken literally?

Comment: @ninamag I did not address that specifically. But if you are asking, I would say that it is no different than how בני ישראל is employed and the usage is context dependent. For example, it Gen. 45:21 it refers to the first generation of Israel's descendants, i.e. his immediate sons. In many other places (Gen 32:33 for example), it means consequent generations, and thus the Jewish nation.